# MVVM: Loosely coupling of ViewModels

Tags: wpf, mvvm, loose-coupling

I have classes, A, B, C, D

A has a reference to E and B and to a list of C and D.

In AViewModel these are exposed in a tree.

The View for A looks like as in the picture.

[image]

When a node selected a correspondent view should be displayed.

There is ViewModels for E,B,C and D

My question is the following:

For example E is the selected node. I store it in AViewModel as "object SelectedItem".
What is the best way to create an EViewModel in a loosely coupled way, so that I do not want to reference EViewModel in AViewModel.

**Update:**

I was thinking about one solution, but I never seen that in other places:

For example I could expose only my POCOs (B, C, D, E) from AViewModel. And in XAML I could bind the ContentControl directly to these objects. With a converter I could have a BViewModel when I bind to B and so on.

Comment: Can you please post your xaml so we dont have to reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 2):

A common and widely accepted way to communicate between view models and other components in a loosely coupled way in an MVVM application would be to use an event aggregator or a messenger. Please refer to the following links for more information.

**Using the event aggregator pattern to communicate between view models:** https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2014/02/28/using-the-event-aggregator-pattern-to-communicate-between-view-models/

**MVVM - Messenger and View Services in MVVM:** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj694937.aspx.

Another option would be to use a shared service that you inject the view models with: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/22907a0f-d805-4195-8272-7c284b72d2ee/example-of-using-shared-services-prism?forum=wpf

Using an event aggregator, messenger or shared service means that you can remove all references between the view model classes.

Instead of the view model classes having strong references to each other back and forth, each view model only knows about a single event aggregator/messenger/shared service and communicates only with this one. View model A may send any number of messages that any other view models may subscribe to listen to and handle internally.

> My question is about best practices on topic of creating an instance of a ViewModel without having a tight coupling, not about the communication between loosely coupled ViewModels

Creating an instance of another view model without creating a string coupling is impossible. If one view model creates an instance of another view model they are by definition strongly coupled. To prevent this you could inject a view model with an interface type that the other view model implements, e.g.:

```
public ViewModelB(IViewModelA viewModelA)
{
    //...
}
```

Then ViewModelB is dependant on an interface type instead of a concrete implementation of the ViewModelA. It's a bit better than doing something like this because then ViewModelA and ViewModelB will always be - as mentioned above - strongly coupled to each other:

```
public ViewModelB()
{
    _viewModelA = new ViewModellA();
}
```

But if you really care about loose coupling between your view model classes, you should get rid of the direct references and start to use an event aggregator or a messenger to communcate between them.

Comment: My question is about best practices on topic of creating an instance of a ViewModel without having a thigt coupling, not about the communication between loosely coupled ViewModels.

Comment: This is impossible. If one view model creates an instance of another view model they are by definition strongly coupled. See my edited answer for more information.

Comment: @jannagy02 Use a factory method and get an (instance of) interface back. Or use DI container like Prism  - you request a type (use interfaces) and get a concrete type back. But for what you specified it sounds like B, C, D and E are all POCOs (which may be wrapped with their own viewmodels) - it's OK for AViewModel to know about them because its job is to shape, transform and present the data to the view.

Comment: @mm8 This is not impossible, for example with factory method as mentioned by slugster also. I added an update to my post.

Comment: If the factory method returns an instance of view model B and you call the factory method in view model A, then view model A is strongly coupled to view model B. Read my answer again.

Comment: @mm8 Factory method return type could be "object" or "ViewModelBase" but not the concrete type.

Comment: Then you might as well put any method that you want to be able to call in the base class directly which means that it makes no sense to create an instance of the other view model.

Answer (score 0):

If your A View displays the "list", plus the selected view, it's perfectly acceptable to have EViewModel reference in AViewModel. ViewModels may be the "reflection" of the views. So if the A view will contain an EView, AViewModel may contain an EViewModel. You just nest your view models so it creates the same tree as in the view layer.

On top of that, what I would do is not reference E or B,... in AViewModel, but reference only EViewModel, BViewModel,... So AView list does not display model classes but ViewModel classes. Your SelectedItem gets typed as a ViewModel and you can directly bind your "Display" view part to the SelectedItem. Then you can use the right DataTemplate on the view layer to display the according view. Hope it helps

Comment: This is what I am doing currently :) But I always felt that this could be done in a better way.